# Is there a way to get Linux to treat an initramfs as the final root filesystem?

Tags: linux, boot, initramfs, initrd

I want to boot a system with an initramfs that's the actual final filesystem, not a temporary initramfs for loading drivers. Unfortunately, Linux imposes different (and in my case, undesirable) behaviors when using initramfs, including at least the following differences:

- devtmpfs is not auto-mounted, at least not at first, but seems to get auto-mounted at some point later which I can't figure out.
- Instead of running `/sbin/init` (or the init program specified by `init=` on the command line) the kernel attempts to invoke `/init`.

I know it's possible to work around these by putting some extra junk on the initramfs, but I'd rather it just behave like a normal root fs. Is there any way to achieve this?

If I do need to work around it with userspace scripting in the initramfs, I at least want to understand what triggers the auto-mounting of devtmpfs.

Comment: of course. it already does. the `init` executable has to explicitly do something like `busybox`'s `switch-root` to do otherwise. so just don't do that and you're golden. and by the way, all that is done in initramfs is *something like userspace scripting* - initramfs is the first userspace. that's its job.

Comment: @mikeserv: Your comment is demonstrably false and does not address the question.

Comment: it is a comment, not an answer, and it is a *true* one.

Comment: @mikeserv: You can observe all the behaviors I described with a trivial initramfs containing nothing but a static-linked program named `init` which lists the contents of `/dev`.

Comment: if you want a devtmpfs on `/dev` that hasn't yet been mounted then just `mount` it. `mount -t devtmpfs none /dev`. again, its just userspace. if your `init` doesnt mount it, then mount it. or, just include the `init` on your current rootfs rather than the one in your initramfs. initramfs is *just* a `/` mount, its always the first one, and everything within it is exactly the kind of stuff youd find elsewhere.

Comment: @mikeserv: The question is how to make an initramfs (linked into the kernel, but that doesn't matter to the question) get treated the way a normal root fs would get treated. If you want to say "Linux does not support that", that would be an answer. Claiming that it's already doing that is false and not helpful.

Comment: it is treated as a normal rootfs already. it is rootfs. if you want what happens in your current rootfs to happen in initramfs then you need the programs located in your current rootfs to also be located in initramfs. thats all. theres no mystery. the *userspace scripting* that the programs on your current rootfs do simply wont  happen in initramfs without those same programs. but linux *definitely* supports that, and it really doesnt have anything to do with linux at all - initramfs is one userspace, your current rootfs is another. mirror the one in the other for duplicate behaviors.

Comment: @mikeserv: That's false. With a normal `root=` root fs, devtmpfs is mounted by default by the kernel (`CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT`) before any userspace processes execute, allowing `/dev/console` to be opened for the init process (by the kernel) without any hard device nodes existing anywhere, and the command specified by `init=` is executed as pid 1. This does not happen with initramfs. The difference in behavior is definitely on the kernel side and not in userspace. It's trivially testable with a fs consisting of a single static-linked program.

Comment: no. youre wrong. it is your `init` executable that handles the `root=` parameter anyway. initramfs is rootfs. in order to get the second rootfs, the `init` has to mount your rootfs *over* `/` - usually with `switch-root`. when you do `root=/dev/sda1` your `init` executable does like: `mount /dev/sda1 /newroot; mount -t devtmpfs none /newroot/dev; mount... ` and the rest and then does `find / -xdev ! -type d -exec rm {} +; switch-root /newroot`. It does that because *thats its script*. if you want it to do something else, then change the script. it has absolutely nothing to with the kernel.

Comment: @mikeserv: My init executable most certainly does not handle `root=` because I wrote it. Please stop trying to answer this question with reasoning based on what your distro is doing. This question is about kernel behavior not typical initrd scripts' behaviors. The `root=` case I'm talking about is when **no initrd whatsoever** exists and the kernel does the mounting.

Comment: there is never an initrd when initramfs is involved. why would there be? thats just silly. if your `init` was written by you and you want it to mount `/dev` then why dont you just tell it to?

Comment: @mikeserv: There are two scenarios I'm comparing whose behaviors differ: (1) no initrd image at all, `root=` processed by the kernel to directly mount the main filesystem, (2) exact same filesystem as in case 1, but linked into the kernel as an initramfs. I want to use exactly the same boot sequence for both, but the kernel insists on starting them differently because it thinks the latter is a temporary fs that will mount the real root fs later. I am asking if there's a way to inhibit this behavior and have the kernel treat both the same.

Comment: well, your *because it thinks* statement is incorrect. the kernel never has anything at all to do with mounting a later rootfs. once an initramfs is mounted as `/` it is the initramfs userspace that has to get the next one - the kernel doesnt ever do that. thats the point of initramfs in the first place. and there is *never* an initrd when there is an initramfs.

Comment: @mikeserv: Are you ignoring everything I've said? In case (1) **there is no initramfs**. The kernel mounts the final (and only) root fs directly. My question is how to get an initramfs treated like a normal root.

Comment: that doesn't mean there is no initramfs - it only means its empty. and no, im not ignoring you. you just dont understand what i say, i guess. my point is that your *kernel* does *not* treat either rootfs differently. if the behaviors are different, then it is the *userspace*'s fault. maybe you should try to figure out why? youre definitely confused at least about how an initrd relates to an initramfs anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv: The distinction between "no initramfs" and "empty initramfs" is inconsequential. Either way, the kernel, not userspace, mounts the filesystem specified by `root=`. You can read this code in `init/do_mounts.c`. It most definitely happens in the kernel because there are no userspace programs in existence at this point.

Comment: ugh. it only does that if there is no initramfs at all - that parameter is ignored by the kernel and typically handled by `init` in most cases because the kernel ignores it when an initramfs is appended to its image or is compiled in. that is the only difference, and the kernels handling of `root=` at all is considered to be a legacy behavior according to the docs.

Comment: The kernel does not ignore it when an initramfs is appended, only when `/init` actually exists in the `initramfs`. Otherwise it tries to mount the `root=` device, mounts devtmpfs, and executes `/sbin/init` (or the `init=` command).

Comment: good point. thats true - poor wording on my part. my apologies. but it seems like you know what the problem is - the kernel only handles that at all as a catch-all for a no `init` situation. so if you need that mount, you have to mount it.

Comment: @mikeserv: Despite being frustrating, discussing this was productive in tracking down the issue. I've added an answer including notes on why I expected what I want to be possible, why it's not practical without modifying the kernel, and how the kernel could be trivially modified to support it.

Answer (score 2):

This is achievable if `CONFIG_BLOCK` is undefined, since `init/do_mounts.c` contains in `mount_root`, which runs after the kernel fails to execute `/init` on the initramfs, the following:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_BLOCK
    {
        int err = create_dev("/dev/root", ROOT_DEV);

        if (err < 0)
            pr_emerg("Failed to create /dev/root: %d\n", err);
        mount_block_root("/dev/root", root_mountflags);
    }
#endif
```

Source: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/do_mounts.c?id=c69e3c3a0c014e86750e78b7e2ae823f7a9b2cb2#n535

In this case, `mount_root` succeeds without having done anything and the kernel proceeds to treat the initramfs as a proper root fs.

Unfortunately, turning `CONFIG_BLOCK` off is not practical for most uses. What led me to believe this should work is that, on the patch for the particular development board I'm working with, the condition was replaced with:

```
#if defined(CONFIG_BLOCK) && !defined(CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE)
```

It would be nice to add support for `root=initramfs` that causes `mount_root` to return without doing anything, and this should be a trivial one-line patch. I have no idea whether it would be acceptable upstream, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is rather late but I have an answer that might help you:

First off, you'll want to include /dev/console in your initramfs.  This will allow you to get sysinit functionality reporting back to the console (prints from userspace will again show up on your main display).  Next, if you are using busybox for your init process, add a sym-link to busybox in the root of your RFS called init.  The problem is that the Linux kernel filesystem layer changed a few years back.  Originally, you HAD to have /init to launch the system.  This was thought of as a security hole and was relocated to /sbin/init.  Later, IIRC, this became linuxrc but I believe it has been removed all together now.

In my inittab, the first two lines are mount proc and mount devtmpfs.  All seems to work correctly.